# Solid cross-platform threads support in GUIs: tkinter, pygtk, wxpython or pyqt

Tags: wxpython, pyqt, tkinter, pygtk, python-multithreading

I have some experience with pygtk, and I feel very comfortable with, except
when the threads are necessary on windows, so I was wondering, 
**how does my fellows programmers deals with threads in tkinter, pyqt and wxpython in a cross-platform environment (or at least linux-windows)?**.

I'll really appreciate sample threading code, with each toolkit.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're interested in some advice I picked up regarding cross platform threads in GTK, check out [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/pygtk@daa.com.au/msg19404.html) and some code I scratched up on [GitHub](https://github.com/detly/gtk-async-test).

Comment: I haven't used PyQt4/PySide's thread system, but they're said to work well (cross-platform).

Comment: I've used PyQt4 for multi-threading in a couple small applications and it has been very solid and easy to use.  These applications have worked on Windows and OS X without any problems.  Just make sure to use only Qt threads and not mix Python and Qt threads (they both use the same low level calls, but don't really play well together).

Answer (score 1):

For wxPython, check out the following links:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/